# Nexus 7 Doesn't Show Up As Media Device (MTP)

Tags: windows-7, mtp, nexus-7

When connecting my **Nexus 7** to my Windows 7 computer, it doesn't show up in neither `Windows Explorer > My Computer` nor `Device Manager > Portable Devices`.

I did, however, install the Google USB driver, which allows USB debugging for Android development, and that driver shows up under `Device Manager > Android Devices`

[image]

Also, when the Nexus 7 is connected via USB to the Windows 7 Computer, the setting on the device is correctly selected/checked to connect as a media device: `Notifications (Swipe down) > USB Computer Connection > Connect as Media Device (MTP)`

However, when I connect my **Galaxy Nexus** phone, it shows up in both `Device Manager > Android Devices` and `Device Manager > Portable Devices`, which in turn shows up under `Windows Explorer > My Computer` allowing me to actually use it as an MTP device.

[image]

How can I access my Nexus 7 as a media device under Windows 7?

Comment: Android phones typically ask for permission before going into storage device mode. I'm surprised your phone hasn't done that. Is it possible that it did and you missed it?

Comment: It's possible that this happened on the Nexus 7.  But if it did, how can i make it ask for permission again?

Comment: Same issue here.. naked drivers do the same, only thing is now it says Nexus.. but still no storage drive.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As I posted in [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35635/nexus-7-wont-show-up-as-a-drive-on-windows-in-mtp-mode-after-update-to-android) question on Android.SE, I was able to get my MTP mode working again. FYI I don't know how this affects the debugging interface since I haven't checked that out yet, but this should let you access it as a drive.

From that answer (slightly modified based on your images):

> What worked for me (on Windows) was:
>
> 1. Plug the Nexus 7 into your computer with the USB cable.
> 2. Open Device Manager.
> 3. Find "Android Device" near the top and expand the node. Double click on "Android Composite ADB Interface".
> 4. In the properties window that pops up, uninstall the driver (I chose to delete the current driver as well, not sure if that matters).
> 5. Unplug the tablet and plug it back in.
>
> At this point mine got recognized as a Nexus 7 instead of an Android
>   ADB device and allowed me to transfer files again.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I can't update the driver since Windows 7 tells me that the currently installed driver is the most recent version.  Deleting the driver and then plugging back in the device only reinstalled the same driver.

Comment: That's too bad. I was so happy when I got it working. Perhaps you can try installing the [naked drivers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1161769)?

Comment: `I chose to delete the current driver as well, not sure if that matters` - this matters. It looks like this problem appears when you are using another (second) Nexus 7 device on the same computer. After I did all the steps here, MTP worked with a fresh drivers copy from Windows Update, but ADB got broken. Using drivers from http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=Nexus%207 fixed that and all is working - for now.

Comment: This worked for me. I replaced my Galaxy Nexus phone with a Nexus 5 and was unable to get MTP working on the Nexus 5 until I uninstalled and deleted the old driver.

Comment: Everything works for me now, but I'm still not sure why.  It only started working after I updated my Nexus 7 to Android 4.4 (Kit Kat, which is not supported for the Galaxy Nexus phone) and then updated the driver from Asus's website.  So now my Phone is using Android 4.3 and my tablet is using Android 4.4 and they now both connect as MTP devices.  I'll accept your answer as correct based on votes.