# Nexus 4 not recognized on Windows 10

Tags: usb, windows-10, drivers, android, mtp

I have Nexus 4 with Lollipop and enabled MTP in settings. My Windows 10 N PC won't recognize it. I tried to install [Google USB driver](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html), but when I choose path to driver folder `...\usb_driver` -> check include subfolders -> next. I get following message:

[image]

I have also downloaded [Media Feature Pack for N and KN version of Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=48231) and it still not working.

**After clean reinstall of Windows 10 it started to work normally...**

Comment: Have you tried the answer on this thread? http://superuser.com/questions/526571/nexus-7-doesnt-show-up-as-media-device-mtp

Comment: @Moab I have checked MTP

Comment: @Papa Yes, I don't have any Android Device node.

Comment: See answer on this page, using device manager to solve it.   https://www.reddit.com/r/nexus4/comments/3lurow/nexus_4_windows_10/

Comment: I found a different nexus driver page, and it has video tutorial on how to properly install also..http://androidmtk.com/download-google-nexus-usb-drivers

Comment: @Moab Thanks for links, but it give me same message as on picture above.

Comment: Did you do the manual install of the driver using device manager? Watch the video tutorial.